# Toggling CSS property off and on changes apperance

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a menu button that is an image with text at the bottom, like so:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aurck25v/39/)

On jsfiddle it works fine, but when I load my page "title" element instead of being at the bottom of the parent is on top of it (outside of its parents border): [bad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Go1m.png)

In my code I have a-tags instead of divs, because on jsfiddle it didn't look correct with a-tag, but I don't think it is a problem, because I tried with divs in my code, and the "bug" is still present and the apperance does not change:

```
<a class="menu-item" href="#">
    <p>Title</p>
</a>
```

After toggling one of titles properties in inspect mode (text-align, width, bottom or margin) off and then on it is now as it should be: [good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3blzO.png) What? Why?

While trying to fix this I found out that when I remove "margin: auto" from .menu-item it no longer happens, but it's obviously not a solution, because now my buttons are not centered.

```
.menu-item {
  margin: auto;
}
```

I'm a newb in CSS, so only solution that comes to my mind is to toggle one of the properties with JS, but that seems a bit hacky and I'm sure there is a better way. I tried chaning order of styles in .css file, but it did nothing.

So my question is: Why is this happening (not changing anything in css styles, just toggling off and on, changes apperance) and what can I do to fix this?

Edit:

My local files:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="top">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="center">
            <div class="menu">
                <div id="left-mi" class="menu-item" href="#">
                    <p class="mi-title">Title</p>
                </div>
                <a id="middle-mi" class="menu-item" href="#"></a>
                <a id="right-mi" class="menu-item" href="#"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="center">
        </div>
        <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="center"></div>
        <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

styles.css

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background: steelblue;
}

.left, .center, .right {
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
}

.left, .right {
    width: auto;
}

.center {
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
}

.top, .middle, .bottom {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.mi-title {
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width: 100%;

    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.menu-item {
    height: 80%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 30%;
    position: relative;
}

.menu {
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    background: magenta;

    display: flex;
}

/*#region Heights*/
.top {
height: 200px;
}
.middle {
height: 300px;
}
.bottom {
height: 100px;
}
/*#endregion*/
/*#region Borders*/
.top .center, .bottom .center, .middle > div {
border: 1px solid black;
}
.top .center, .bottom .center {
border-top: 0;
border-bottom: 0;
}
.middle .left, .middle .right {
border-left: 0;
border-right: 0;
}
/*#endregion*/
/*#region Debug Colors*/
#left-mi {
background: red;
}
#middle-mi {
background: green;
}
#right-mi {
background: blue;
}

.top .left {
background: rgb(80, 0, 0);
}
.top .center {
background: rgb(160, 0, 0);
}
.top .right {
background: rgb(250, 0, 0);
}

.middle .left {
background: rgb(0, 80, 0);
}
.middle .center {
background: rgb(0, 160, 0);
}
.middle .right {
background: rgb(0, 250, 0);
}

.bottom .left {
background: rgb(0, 0, 80);
}
.bottom .center {
background: rgb(0, 0, 160);
}
.bottom .right {
background: rgb(0, 0, 250);
}
/*#endregion*/
```

Comment: This works fine for me on Chrome and Firefox using the code in your fiddle. Can you confirm that I am using the correct code on the browser that you  have the issue with?

Comment: Fiddle looks fine for me, but the problem is in index.html (see edit)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. Keep adjusting the left until you have the button centered. There may be a better solution but I think this works fine.

```
<a class="menu-item" href="#">
    <p>Title</p>
</a>
```

And the corresponding CSS can be

```
.menu-item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: none;
  left:43%;
  position: relative;
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: This button is part of menu, so there will be more than 1 of those (I'm not sure how many yet), so I'm using flexbox to distibute them evenly.